# sentence explanation and ,,sentence synonyms" - Only when that is done do we have a class from which we can create objects

Tags: structure

I am reading about C++ computer programming (Stroustrup's book - for the keens) and I have just met with this sentence.

> **Only when that is done do we have a class from which we can create objects.**

It is quite straightforward I think and I understand it (I hope so).  My problem is that I don't remember a sentence structure like this.

Could you please make things clear for me and make some other examples and / or alternatives to this using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence *Only when that is done do we have a class from which we can create objects* features one of the cases in which the subject and the verb are inverted in English.

Swan in *Practical English Usage* has a section with the title *(Inversion) after negative and restrictive expressions* (p280). He writes:

> If a negative adverb or adverbial expression is put at the beginning
>   of a clause for emphasis, it is usually followed by **auxiliary verb +
>   subject**. These structures are mostly rather formal.
>
> - Under no circumstances can we cash cheques.
> - At no time was the President aware of what was happening. 
>     ...
>
> Inversion is also used after restrictive words like *hardly* (in BrE), *seldom, rarely, little* and *never*, and after **only + time expression**. This is formal or literary.
>   ...
>
> - Only then did I understand what she meant.
> - Only after her death was I able to appreciate her.
> - Not only did we lose our money, but we were nearly killed.

As non-inversion alternatives to your sentence you could write :

- It is not until that is done that we have a class from which we can create objects.
- We have a class from which we can create objects only after that is done.